# Is there any way to input command into running "cmd" that we called before? FFMPEG

Tags: c#, cmd, ffmpeg

So, i tried to build some apps that can record my computer's screen (i'm using ffmpeg).
To record my screen i need to input some arguments into cmd, so i made a button that will run cmd and arguments on it when clicked, but here is the problem:
the record process need to be stopped by pressing "q" or "ctrl+c",
is that possible to input some extra command on running cmd?
because while recording my screen, i don't want to see the cmd panel, because the app will do something and i need to record it, so i hide it, when the process that i need to record is completed i need to stop the record process through pressing one single button,
is this possible?

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
```

thanks!

Comment: Why run `cmd` and not run the process directly? You could likely redirect the input stream and send a `q` to the process

Comment: Do you need to stop recording programmatically, i.e. have a program that will send **`q`** to recorder, or it's OK to do it manually?

Comment: Why not using screen recording software installed by default with Windows 10? I don't see any reason after reading your question to reinvent a screen recording software. For other Windows versions there are dozens of freeware Windows GUI applications available for screen recording.

Comment: @ThomasWeller as far as i know, is using `cmd`, any other way to use FFMPEG record function without using `cmd`? and how to do it? any reference?

@AlexCohn yes, i need to stop this process programmatically, without doin it manually

@Mofi i need to build this record function because the main function of this application is way larger than just recording, i need this application to had its own recording function, so i cant use any other third party application, beside its included inside my application sir